# Office 365 Product Usage Data API Permissions and Data Format

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I had two questions regarding the new Graph reporting APIs for Office 365 product usage data as described here:  https://blogs.office.com/2017/03/31/whats-new-in-office-365-administration-public-preview-of-microsoft-graph-reporting-apis/.

1. When will a set of permissions for accessing this data show up in the Azure portal for Microsoft Graph?  For example, so we can build apps where people can consent to us using that permission to retrieve their data.
2. The data format is CSV, which really does not lend itself to any kind of service-based consumption.  Is there any other means by which you can get the data as JSON or Xml?  If not, any idea if that might happen by RTM?

Comment: Did you get answers to your questions?  I am trying to work out how to handle the CSV response - I am going to try and write it directly to a storage account as a CSV file after which I can read it in via Spark or similar